# iOS Enterprise Deployment review time?

Tags: ios, ios-enterprise

I'm planning to distribute my app **In-house** , I know that **iOS Developer** distribution on the **App Store** often takes a long time.

Does the **iOS Enterprise Program** have a review process?

How long does it generally take?

Will the app need to be reviewed again after each update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of in-house distribution is to distribute *outside* of the App Store, thus your apps are not on it, and are not reviewed by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

There is no review process of Enterprise Applications.